# Get road distance with MapKit - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

What are the classes I should look into if I want to get road distance?

All I want to be able to get is the road-distance from point A to point B, I don't need to show step by step directions nor the map.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to make a [MKDirections](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKDirections_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKDirections) request. From [calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKDirections_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKDirections/calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:) you will get a [MKDirectionsResponse](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKDirectionsResponse_class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/MKDirectionsResponse). This has a [routes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKDirectionsResponse_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKDirectionsResponse/routes) array of [MKRoutes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKRoute_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKRoute). Each route has a [distance](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKRoute_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKRoute/distance) (i.e. road distance) property.

```
    let source = MKMapItem( placemark: MKPlacemark(
        coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-41.27, 173.28),
        addressDictionary: nil))
    let destination = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(
        coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-41.11, 173),
        addressDictionary: nil))

    let directionsRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
    directionsRequest.source = source
    directionsRequest.destination = destination

    let directions = MKDirections(request: directionsRequest)

    directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler { (response, error) -> Void in
        print(error)
        let distance = response!.routes.first?.distance // meters
        print("\(distance! / 1000)km")
    }
```

Comment: I get this every time I use this code
Error Domain=MKErrorDomain Code=3 "Directions Not Available" UserInfo=0x7fc96da18bf0 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=Route information is not available at this moment., MKErrorGEOError=-4, MKDirectionsErrorCode=2, NSLocalizedDescription=Directions Not Available}
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: You need to make sure the source and destination are located in a country where Apple Maps Directions is supported. Please see the following link: https://www.apple.com/ios/feature-availability/#maps-directions